# How to return all documents from a neo4j vector store in langchain?

Tags: neo4j, langchain

How can I return all documents from a neo4j vector store in langchain?
Is there a wildcard I can use with the neo4jVector.search() function to return a list of all document objects?

I want to be able to know which documents were already added before I add more pdfs in the vectorstore from a folder that contains pdfs added already in the store previously.

thank you!